# Re-ordering of the rows and columns in a CSR matrix

Tags: python, scipy, networkx, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a matrix in a sparse csr format for example:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
M  = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)) 
M.A = 
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

I am re-ordering the matrix with the index [2,0,1] using the following approach:

```
order = np.array([2,0,1])
M = M[order,:]
M = M[:,order]
M.A
array([[6, 4, 5],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [3, 0, 0]])
```

This approach works but it is not feasible for my real csr_matrix which has the size of  `16580746 X 1672751804` and causes memory error.
I took another approach like this:

```
edge_list = zip(row,col,dat)
index = dict(zip(order, range(len(order))))
all_coeff = zip(*((index[u], index[v],d) for u,v,d in edge_list if u in index and v in index))
new_row,new_col,new_data = all_coeff
n = len(order)
graph  = csr_matrix((new_data, (new_row, new_col)), shape=(n, n))
```

This also works but fall into the same trap of memory error for large sparse matrix. Any suggestions to efficiently do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found using matrix operations to be the most efficient. Here's a function which will permute the rows and/or columns to a specified order. It can be modified to swap two specific rows/columns if you would like.

```py
from scipy import sparse

def permute_sparse_matrix(M, new_row_order=None, new_col_order=None):
    """
    Reorders the rows and/or columns in a scipy sparse matrix 
        using the specified array(s) of indexes
        e.g., [1,0,2,3,...] would swap the first and second row/col.
    """
    if new_row_order is None and new_col_order is None:
        return M
    
    new_M = M
    if new_row_order is not None:
        I = sparse.eye(M.shape[0]).tocoo()
        I.row = I.row[new_row_order]
        new_M = I.dot(new_M)
    if new_col_order is not None:
        I = sparse.eye(M.shape[1]).tocoo()
        I.col = I.col[new_col_order]
        new_M = new_M.dot(I)
    return new_M
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's think smart.

Instead of reordering the matrix, why don't you work directly on the row and column indexes that you provided at the start?

So for example, you can replace your row indexes in this way, from:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

to:

```
[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

And your column indexes, from:

```
[0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

to:

```
[2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Ok I understand row and column replacement, but how to update data then?

Comment: @MohanTimilsina you should reload your data. You can get data, rows and columns indexes from csr matrix (there are parameters called indices, data, etc). After obtaining that you can change the indexes as you please